# How to exclude a particular file when converting js coverage lcov file to cobertura XML

Tags: python, jenkins, code-coverage, cobertura, lcov

I am using python script to convert lcov file to cobertura format so that I can use Jenkins plugin to show the report in the job. I need to exclude few packages and some files, the python script only provides option to exclude packages. Any other workaround?

https://github.com/eriwen/lcov-to-cobertura-xml

Excludes the entire package,
python lcov_cobertura.py lcov.info --excludes sources.modules.web.services.transport -o coverage1.xml

I want to exclude on the "BundleService.js" under transport package,
(This doesn't work)
python lcov_cobertura.py lcov.info --excludes sources.modules.web.services.transport.BundleService -o coverage2.xml

Tried multiple regex, still no luck.

Answer (score 0):

### Solution 1

They use `re.match` in [`lcov_cobertura.py`](https://github.com/eriwen/lcov-to-cobertura-xml/blob/master/lcov_cobertura/lcov_cobertura.py) to apply `excludes`.

In python documentation for [`re.match`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) it is written:

> re.match(pattern, string, flags=0)
>
> If zero or more characters at the beginning of string match the regular expression pattern, return a corresponding MatchObject instance. Return None if the string does not match the pattern; note that this is different from a zero-length match.

It means that it searchs from the beggining of package name. And you should specify argument like the following to avoid any starting symbols:

```
-e ".*sources.modules.web.services.transport"
```

The quotes are needed to avoid shell expansion for `*` (important for Linux shells like bash).
The complete command looks like:

```
python lcov_cobertura.py lcov.info --excludes ".*sources.modules.web.services.transport" -o coverage1.xml
```

### Solution 2

Maybe removing data about specific package in lcov is better idea:

```
lcov --capture --directory $BINDIR --output-file lcov.info
lcov --remove lcov.info "*sources.modules.web.services.transport" --output-file lcov.info
```

As mentioned in [`man lcov`](http://ltp.sourceforge.net/coverage/lcov/lcov.1.php):

> Use this switch if you want to remove coverage data for  a  particular  set  of files from a tracefile. Additional command line parameters will be interpreted as shell wildcard patterns ...
>
> The  result of the remove operation will be written to stdout or the tracefile specified with -o.